# How to check for Null on a `SqlString` in VB.Net 2.0?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, .net-2.0

I have a property of type `SqlString` which is currently returning Null.

`_oData.Customer.Name`

Here are the following checks I have tried that have not worked.

```
IsNothing(_oData.Customer.Name)
_oData.Customer.Name.IsNull
_oData.Customer.Name.Value IsNot Nothing
_oData.Customer.Name = Nothing
```

Each of those results in the error below. How does one really check for the value being Null.

> Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

`_oData.Customer` has values on the other properties.

**EDIT**

Adding the class which has the name property. Here is how it is defined in the `Customer` class

```
   Private mName As SqlTypes.SqlString

   Public Property Name() As SqlTypes.SqlString
        Get
            Return mName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As SqlTypes.SqlString)
            mName = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

SqlString as seen in the SqlTypes Namespace
[image]

**EDIT-2**

Ok seems to be an issue with the way ternery operations are being handled

This works

```
If _oData.Customer.Name.IsNull Then
    CName = ""
Else
    CName = _oData.Customer.Name
End If
```

This doesn't

```
CName = IIf(_oData.Customer.Name.IsNull, "", _oData.Customer.Name.Value)
```

Can anyone tell me why this doesnt work when using a ternary operation?

Comment: What do you mean by `SqlString` there is no such NET datatype.  If you mean `DbType.String` then its just a string.  Not sure what you are asking but `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` is probably what you are after

Comment: Are you sure that Customer or _oData are not null? (Nothing)

Comment: @Steve: yep, thats the first thing I checked. The other properties on it are having values

Comment: @Plutonix: Its there is in  `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll` under `System.Data.SqlTypes` namespace

Comment: surprisingly `_oData.Customer.Name.IsNull` has a value of `True`, but when I call it, it returns the same error as in my post above.

Comment: I've added the code where Name is declared. I unfortunately can't change that piece of code as its legacy. Is there no way such a type can be checked for Null? It does have a property called IsNul on it though. Why can't I use that?

Comment: You've tagged your question with ADO.NET but you've also said that this property is on a regular class.  How exactly are you populating this property then?

Comment: @jmcilhinney: tag of Ado.net because the type `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString` is part of ado.net? The legacy code which I am trying to work thru is assigning it like this  `Dim Colindex As Integer = DataReader.GetOrdinal(ColName);       If DataReader.IsDBNull(Colindex) Then
            Variable = SqlTypes.SqlString.Null
        Else
            Variable = DataReader.GetSqlString(Colindex)
        End If` where `GetSqlString` is a method on `System.Data.SqlClient`. I've put the semicolon to separate statements for this comment box. Its not in the actual code.

Comment: The values in Variable is then assigned to the property `Name` passed in as a ByRef variable.

Comment: Check the Edit 2 in the post above. Some new findings

Comment: Why have you chosen to use `SqlString` in your own type rather than just `String`?

Comment: thats how I inherited the code. the problem was not with sql string. It was with the `IIf` statement in vb.net. I was using a ternary with `IIf`instead of `If`. To quote user @itsLex `the IIf function does not use short-circuit evaluation, it always evaluates all three of its arguments.`

Comment: I didn't say that the problem was with the `SqlString` but that doesn't mean that using it in your own type is a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsDBNull() Method:

```
If IsDBNull(_oData.Customer.Name) Then
```

Comment: still getting the same error `Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.`

Comment: Check the Edit 2 in the post above

Comment: That's ironic. But it is a known fact that `Because the IIf function does not use short-circuit evaluation, it always evaluates all three of its arguments. ` ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx))

Comment: ah! didn't know that, coming from a C# background. Thanks. Mystery Solved.